# Python : Alternative to biip lib for python 3.6 or earlier

Tags: python, barcode

Do you have any alternatives to the biip lib? I read the documentation and it says it is avaible only for Python 3.7 or later.

Or do you have any suggestions to backport it to earlier version?

Here is the [doc link](https://biip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I sent an email to the conceptor.
He said : "I've done the work required to get Biip running on Python 3.6 and
released it as Biip 0.6".
So we are fine now.